# If MAX(id) != COUNT(id), does that mean rows have been deleted?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1, auto-increment

The question pretty much says it all. We're talking MySQL here, version 5.1.

What I'm wondering is whether this would strictly means rows have been deleted, or if there are other possible scenarios that could cause this: weird locking or race conditions, etc. that force the table's `ID` counter to increment multiple times for a single insertion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you are asking about columns with the `AUTO_INCREMENT` property.

No, deleted rows is not the only reason, there are several others:

- inserts that did not succeed (due to duplicate unique or primary key violations or other reasons).
- inserts inside transactions that did not commit and were rolled back.
- inserts where the `id` was explicitely defined (and id numbers were skipped or negative values added). In the second case, you can have `MAX(id)` less than `COUNT(id)` as a result.
- variation of the previous case: column was not `AUTO_INCREMENT` when the table was created - so there were explicit inserts for some period - and then modified.
- updates of the auto-incrementing column.
- the `id` was set to start from a value different than the default `1`.
- the auto_increment step setting (system variable: [`auto_increment_increment`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment)) of the server is not `1` (or had been changed to something else than `1` for some period).
- and (something that is usually neglected because the `id` is usually the primary key), the column was not defined as the `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` key. That allows duplicates and one more case where the `MAX` can be lower than the `COUNT`.
- a variation of the above is (with MyISAM engine) an auto-incrementing column that is part of a composite primary key.