# Manually increase AUTO_INCREMENT column by one

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I was wondering if there is a simple way to manually increase the auto increment vaulue of a MySQL column by one.

The use case would be to keep the indexes in sync of two tables. In my case they usually both get a new entry at the same time. But sometimes only one of them gets a new entry. This causes the IDs to desync, which is not what I want. Due to limitations in the code I cannot retrieve the ID of any inserted rows, as there's a fair amount of limitations on the API I use to communicate with the database. I can however execute queries to my hearts content. So a simple query to bump the value by one would be much apprechiated!

Comment: So, lets say one table has IDs 1,2,3,4,7,8 and the other has 1,2,4,7,8,9. Do you want the IDs to be updated so they match?

Comment: just insert a record then delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make no promises with this one, but you might get away with the following:

For a table `mytable` in the `mydb` database

```
SET @src_db = 'mydb';
SET @src_tb = 'mytable';
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',@src_db,'.',@src_tb,' AUTO_INCREMENT=',auto_increment+1)
INTO @sql FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema=@src_db AND table_name=@src_tb;
PREPARE s FROM @sql; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

After running this, you can verify with

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE mydb.mytable\G
```

I just tried this with a table `ganeshbora.customer` on my Windows laptop (5.7.12)

## SAMPLE CODE

```
SET @src_db = 'ganeshbora';
SET @src_tb = 'customer';
SHOW CREATE TABLE ganeshbora.customer\G
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',@src_db,'.',@src_tb,' AUTO_INCREMENT=',auto_increment+1)
INTO @sql FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema=@src_db AND table_name=@src_tb;
SELECT @sql;
PREPARE s FROM @sql;
EXECUTE s;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
SHOW CREATE TABLE ganeshbora.customer\G
```

## SAMPLE CODE EXECUTED

```
mysql> SET @src_db = 'ganeshbora';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @src_tb = 'customer';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE ganeshbora.customer\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: customer
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `cust_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cust_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',@src_db,'.',@src_tb,' AUTO_INCREMENT=',auto_increment+1)
    -> INTO @sql FROM information_schema.tables
    -> WHERE table_schema=@src_db AND table_name=@src_tb;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @sql;
+---------------------------------------------------+
| @sql                                              |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| ALTER TABLE ganeshbora.customer AUTO_INCREMENT=15 |
+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> PREPARE s FROM @sql;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> EXECUTE s;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE ganeshbora.customer\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: customer
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `cust_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cust_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

As shown, the auto_increment of the table was incremented from `14` to `15`. Of course, I did this with all privileges:

```
mysql> SELECT user(),current_user();
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| user()                    | current_user()            |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| rolandomysqldba@localhost | rolandomysqldba@localhost |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW GRANTS;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for rolandomysqldba@localhost                                           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'rolandomysqldba'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

***So, if you have the necessary grants to do this ...***

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

## UPDATE 2018-06-12 14:57 EDT

[A comment from JohnathanFite](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/209397/manually-increase-auto-increment-column-by-one/209412?noredirect=1#comment410126_209412) brings up a valid point:

> How is this going to be safe for multiple users at a time? I can see using it to fix it when it's out of sync, but at least warn the OP that running this in a multi-user environment is going to cause problems

While this answer will fix the AUTO_INCREMENT in a perfect world, we don't live in a perfect world. You would need application downtime (1-2 min) to freeze writes and current auto_increment values. If you attempt my answer in a live system, you can quickly screw up auto_increment values because rollbacks of INSERTs against a table with auto_increment values will produce gaps. In many cases, the gap increment may be more than 1 due to bulk inserts that rollback.

Please read my old post from `May 12, 2015` : [MySQL auto increment column increases after insertion error occurs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101320/mysql-auto-increment-column-increases-after-insertion-error-occurs/101322#101322) to see how auto_increment gaps are generated.

Comment: Man. I really hoped this would be simpler...

Comment: This is just doing it in pure Dynamic SQL in MySQL. If you are using Java/Javascript/PHP or some other language, you just code two SQL statements and do the following: 1) Retrieve result of `SELECT auto_increment+1 FROM information_schema.tables ...`, 2) `ALTER TABLE db.tb AUTO_INCREMENT=newnumber`.

Comment: How is this going to be safe for multiple users at a time?  I can see using it to fix it when it's out of sync, but at least warn the OP that running this in a multi-user environment is going to cause problems.

Comment: @JonathanFite very valid point. I will update my answer in light of your comment

Comment: Would inserting and immediately deleteing a dummy entry work too? Like `INSERT INTO tb (id) VALUES (NULL); DELETE FROM tb WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Comment: It should work and would be more concise. The tradeoff would be manually introducing fragmentation in the table but would be better for a live environment. My answer would not introduce fragmentation but would require a little downtime and must be done by a user with full privileges.